How can I make both tabs and drawer navigators visible on all screens in an Expo app using expo-router 3?
I am developing an expo SDK 51 app using expo-router 3.5 and attempting to integrate both tab and drawer navigators so they remain visible across all screens. Is there a standard approach or example for achieving this in Expo apps?
I've managed to nest one navigator within the other, I.e. app/(tabs)/(drawer)
...but then the navigators are only both visible when I'm on a (tabs) screen, with the tabs navigator disappearing when navigating to child routes within the (drawer).
Alternatively, could I add all of my screens to the (tabs) folder and then somehow hide a selection of them from the tabs navigation bar?
